# App crashes in simulator when device is changed to iPad Retina

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5

I want to test my iPad app in Retina mode in the iOS simulator. It runs fine in non-retina mode.

However, when selecting `Hardware / Device / iPad Retina`, my app crashes and Xcode breaks  in the line

`return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]))`

No error message is presented.

Any ideas on what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced same issue. but i resolved it in this way-

```
1- Clean Your Code (Product > Clean),
2- Clean Your build folder (holding the Option-Key while redoing the last step) and
3- Changing the Simulator Device once.
```

Comment: You don't need 1 if you do 2

Answer (score 2):

Reset Simulator iPad retina , Clean your project and run again.

***Note: Due to low reputation i have to put as answer.***